# Append data record to laravel elequent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model for user activity history

I also store today's information in the Redis database.

At a specific time, the Redis information is stored in the history model and there is no need to call the Redis information.

In the history model, there is one history for each user per day.

I need when the history model is called, along with that data today as the last record.
Until this information enters the history model.

Is it possible to define these in the model?

Or should each user receive and merge today's information after receiving the history information?

userHistoryModel:

```
    user_id |      date    | activity | otherData1| otherData2
 -----------+--------------+----------+---------- +----------
      1     |   2021-08-01 | 9693.00  | 9523.00   |     1
      2     |   2021-08-01 | 9320.00  | 9341.00   |     2
      3     |   2021-08-01 | 9321.00  | 92245.00  |     3
      1     |   2021-08-02 | 9320.00  | 9412.00   |     4
      2     |   2021-08-02 | 9320.00  | 9325.00   |     5
      1     |   2021-08-03 | 45623.00 | 45550.00  |     1
      2     |   2021-08-03 | 47725.00 | 48500.00  |     2
      3     |   2021-08-03 | 49448.00 | 49787.00  |     3
      2     |   2021-08-04 | 48768.00 | 46251.00  |     4
      3     |   2021-08-04 | 49800.00 | 41254.00  |     5
      3     |   2021-08-05 | 623.00   | 854.00    |     1
```

RedisHash:user:1

```
 --------------+--------------
  user_id      |       1      
  date         |   2021-08-01 
  activity     |   7485.25    
  otherData1   |   87484.87   
  otherData2   |      7
```

Comment: Hello, I've never used Redis personally but this sounds like the perfect opportunity to use a Queued Job that dispatches at the same time the Redis information is stored in the history model. Tried this?

Comment: Hi, it seems like you need a Redis' pub/sub for this to do it automatically. Basically how it works is whenever your Redis inserts a row in the database, Redis will publish the inserted data to a topic. Inside your Laravel project, you need to always listen to this topic for any incoming data. When you've received the data, in this case, insert Redis' published data to your Laravel's database. That way, whenever you try to query the History model, you will always get the latest.

Comment: The Redis data changes every minute, and I think it would be a mistake to update the history model every minute